# SP Relay State in SAML response

Tags: saml-2.0

How to setup a Relaying Party Trust (ADFS2) so that the SAML response returns the Relay State received in the SAML request in a SP initiated trust? Tried POST with "relayState=" at the end, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Refer: [ADFS : RelayState with IDPInitiated](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/11/adfs-relaystate-with-idpinitiated.html).

Have you turned on RelayState as per the link in the article.

Note also that RelayState is more an IDP Initiated concept.

"Don't be confused by the fact that RelayState serves two completely separate purposes. For IdPInitiated, the RelayState specifies the landing page at the SP. For SPInitiated it's a way for the SP to maintain state information between sending the AuthnRequest and receiving the SAML response. RelayState may be sent along with the AuthnRequest and the IDP must return this RelayState along with the SAML response."

Comment: Thank you for your comment, nzocmad. I know how to do an IDP RelayState, but for this particular setup the other party wants an SP initiated RelayState. They send it in the request an expect it returned in the SAML response.